# How do I stop apt-get operations listing large amounts of Marking: and Following dep: entries

Tags: apt, package-management

When I run apt-get install|remove operations, the output runs to a hundred or more lines Marking: or Following dep: for a bunch of unrelated packages.

Here's an example of some of the output:

```
Marking: firefox-esr-l10n-en-gb:amd64 52.0esr-16.04.1
Marking: filezilla:amd64 3.15.0.2-1ubuntu1
Marking: kde-spectacle:amd64 17.04.0-0neon+16.04+build8
Marking: openoffice.org-hyphenation:amd64 0.9
Following dep: openoffice.org-hyphenation:amd64 Depends on openoffice.org-updatedicts [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none ), provided by dictionaries-common:amd64 1.26.3 (1/1)
Marking: pcmciautils:amd64 018-8
Marking: python-pam:amd64 0.4.2-13.2ubuntu2
Marking: libaudio2:i386 1.9.4-4
Following dep: libaudio2:i386 PreDepends on multiarch-support [ i386 ] < none -> 2.23-0ubuntu7 > ( libs ), provided by multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu7 (1/1)
Marking: socat:amd64 1.7.3.1-1
Marking: libdirectfb-extra:i386 1.2.10.0-5.1
Following dep: libdirectfb-extra:i386 PreDepends on multiarch-support [ i386 ] < none -> 2.23-0ubuntu7 > ( libs ), provided by multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu7 (1/1)
```

I assume it's just a verbosity setting in apt, but I've had no luck finding it - can anyone help me turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be the `Debug::pkgAutoRemove` option. From `man apt.conf`:

```
Debug::pkgAutoRemove
    Log events related to the automatically-installed status of
    packages and to the removal of unused packages.
```

Although the above description is not entirely helpful, you can confirm by looking at the `apt` source - specifically, `apt-1.3.5/apt-pkg/depcache.cc`:

```
   bool const debug_autoremove = _config->FindB("Debug::pkgAutoRemove", false);
   if(debug_autoremove)
      std::clog << "Marking: " << Pkg.FullName() << " " << Ver.VerStr() << std::endl;
```

You should be able to turn it off by finding and modifying the setting in your `/etc/apt.conf` or `/etc/apt.conf.d/xxx` files, or on the command line using the `-o` option e.g.

```
sudo apt-get -oDebug::pkgAutoRemove=false install foo
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the level of verbosity with that setting must have changed recently. I've had that config option enabled in my standard build for years (hence clearly forgetting about it), and it's only just started making that amount of noise in the last couple of weeks.